# Sorting layer created by Create Layer from Selected Features using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 Standard / Windows 10 Pro.

I am selecting features with a common attribute and then using the Create Layer from Selected Features method to create a new layer to work on. As soon as I sort my new selection layer, its feature count jumps back to the original feature count of the source layer. In effect, I now have a new layer that is an exact duplicate of the source layer.

Are there certain conditions with the source data that might cause this behavior?

Comment: This is a 12+ year old bug that made it into Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that I always run into those kinds of issues when working with Layers that are created from Selected Features. The only time I really use them is if I can't easily select them using a field.

Since you say you are selecting them by an attribute, my suggestion is to use a definition query. Just make a copy of the layer in the Table of Contents, then double click it, go to the Definition Query tab, and put in your query "Your_Field = 'Some Value'". Then you shouldn't have any problems sorting the attribute table.

Comment: Thank, you Matt. I had forgotten all about the Def. Query. Not an optimal solution but worked well enough as this was more of a one-time task. Thanks!